# Is there a standard method for unit testing code where dependencies do not implement interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

Is there a standard method for unit testing code where dependencies do not implement interfaces? For instance, the `System.Net.Http` namespace only exposes concrete classes. If I'm trying to unit test a class which relies upon one of the concrete classes in `System.Net.Http`, should I merely construct an instance of, say, `HttpRequestMessage`, set it's properties and then supply this newly constructed object to the system under test? Would it make sense to subclass `HttpRequestMessage` and have it implement a custom interface which could then be mocked/stubbed?

Comment: When testing with dependencies you want to have those dependencies in you're control. Subclassing/abstracting is not necessarily required. What you really want to do is stub your dependency and make it behave the way your test subject expects it to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The recommended practice is to wrap this object in a class of your creation, which itself implements an interface.  You would then use this wrapper class in your code, and you can then supply mocked versions of this wrapper in place of the real class.  You would not subclass it using this method, but rather contain it and use delegation (not to be confused with delegates!) to forward each method.

For instance, you might create a class HttpRequestMessageWrapper that inherits from IHttpRequestMessage (that you define, including all the public properties of HttpRequestMessage.. although you could probably get by with only implementing the properties you use).

Alternatively, you can use a testing framework that supports shims, which is a framework that essentially does this wrapper for you and replaces calls to the objects with shim versions.  Microsoft Fakes (introduced in VS 2012 MS Test) does this.

Shims are typically used to replace common framework calls, such as DateTime.Now so you can supply a specific value during tests.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense and should allow me the flexibility to make changes to the internal workings of something like HttpRequestMessageWrapper in the future without breaking any contracts.

Comment: @BradfordFisher - that's not really going to change the internal workings of the class, though it would make it easier to replace specific functionality that is called via the interface.  The class you are wrapping will have no knowledge of your wrapper.  I would recommend not changing the behavior of the wrapped class, as this could cause various unexpected problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you have a look at: AutoFixture http://autofixture.codeplex.com/ It helps you construct the object in the way you want. In your example, HttpRequestMessage, you can customize the fixture: `fixture.Customize<HttpRequestMessage>(c => {});` 
There are many examples out there using AutoFixture in Unit Testing. Or you can post the code you want to test here and i can try to help.

Comment: Autofixture is not going to help for most framework classes, since you have to be able to stub the functionality.  For instance, how would using Autofixture help stub the Socket class?  It's only going to help for classes that are essentially POCO's.

Comment: Totally agree with you on that. There is no silver pullet for all cases. In AutoFixture, you can setup mocking framework you want to use. I agree with your answer above but i find myself can do unittest with AutoFixture + RhinoMock (or Moq) in most cases. At least in projects i have done.

Comment: AutoMocking only works with Interfaces and abstract classes, which the point of the question was how to test class that use concrete classes that do NOT implement those.

Answer (score 0):

Another good tool for testing legacy code is [Typemock](http://www.typemock.com/)